# Functionality difference between ORDS & Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, rest, web-services, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

If ORDS alone can expose the data as RESTful service , then what is the need of oracle Apex? What are the benefits that we are getting for using Apex with ORDS ? I am new to ORDS & I am confused why apex is used along with ORDS if ORDS alone can map rest API with SQL queries & return output data in JSON format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

APEX gives you a web-based user interface to administer REST functionality and develop other PL/SQL-based applications and user interfaces. APEX actually runs inside the database (it's all PL/SQL) and uses ORDS (fka the APEX Listener) to present itself through an application server like Tomcat or WebLogic to the web. ORDS by itself requires you to use SQL Developer to administer REST functionality. Here's a high-level description of the architecture: https://apex.oracle.com/en/platform/architecture/ and a FAQ page (if you haven't already seen it): https://www.oracle.com/tools/technologies/faq-rest-data-services.html

Comment: ORDS provides it's own PL/SQL and REST APIs for managing rest services, and as of version 20.2, you can completely development/manage your RESTful Web Services via the built in web client provided by ords (SQL Developer Web)...there is no requirement for APEX, but you do need ORDS to run APEX

Answer (score 1):

Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) allows you to -

- publish RESTful Web Services for your Oracle Database
- REST Enable things like tables, views, and even stored procedures (automatic RESTful Web Services, no code to write or maintain)
- provide SODA for REST for managing your JSON Document Store in the Oracle Database
- provide a database management REST API to do things like kick off data pump jobs and get database performance metrics
- use SQL Developer Web, a single page web application to manage, monitor, and use your Oracle Database
- provide a PL/SQL web gateway, which allows for things like Application Express (APEX) to work...you make a call, the database generates HTML for your browser to render

[image]

Yes, APEX provides a development interface for the REST features in ORDS, but you don't have to use it. This is also provided a PL/SQL API, SQL Developer on your desktop, or SQL Developer Web (in your browser).

As for APEX itself, it allows you to quickly build and deliver web applications from inside your Oracle Database. It leverages ORDS to make them available via HTTP(S).